# PHP headers to serve ZIP. It downloads but is corrupt... why?

Tags: php, download, header, zip, readfile

Good morning,

I'm working on serving a zip file through the PHP headers, which downloads, but every time I try to extract it shows that the zip is corrupt... I need a 2nd pair of eyes to look over this... what am I missing? Thank you so much!

```
$file_download = 'example';

if (isset($file_download)) {
$file = 'path/to/file/'.$file_download.'.zip';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'File does not exist!';
}
```

}

Comment: Usually when something like that happens, I check the downloaded file in a text editor. There's probably a php error. What might be the problem is that there is two times `.zip` in the resulting filename.

Comment: Are you POSITIVE that the file you are sending is not corrupt before you send it?

Comment: @Daan sorry i was writing off my head... there isn't two .zips... also, the zip sits in a "vault" folder, which checks to see if the file exists before it's sent

Comment: @Andrew so, did you check the file that gets sent to you?

Comment: @Riggs POSITIVE that the file is not corrupt... if i ftp in a grab the file directly, it extracts just fine... thank you for helping, please if there is anything else you can think of please let me know and thank you!

Comment: @Daan thank you for the suggestion! when looking at the zip in my text editor i can see now that some html sneaked it's way in. thank you for helping my find my issue!!

Comment: Do a diff of the original and the downloaded file. If it's only got one or two small errors then it's probably something wrong with your (actual) code. If it's completely off, it's probably going through a compression filter on a buffer or similar.

Comment: @Walf thank you! the issue was that there was html being generated via a template that was being used to serve the code... i couldn't see this till Daan suggested viewing the source. once i did that it was clear to see what was going on. all is fixed... i'm super Happy. thank you all!!